# Keyboard shortcuts for navigating working files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a web developer accustomed to Sublime Text. Often I'll have multiple files open and will navigate between them with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> (or +<kbd>right</kbd>).

I'd love to have something as close to this functionality as possible in Visual Studio Code. From what I've read, in Visual Studio Code it sounds like instead of having multiple documents open in tabs across the top, you're supposed to use the "Working Files" list in the sidebar on the left. A few questions:

- Is there a keyboard shortcut for navigating between these files sequentially? (the equivalent to <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> (or +<kbd>right</kbd>) in Sublime Text?)
- Is there a keyboard shortcut for closing a file and removing it from the working files list? <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> just closes its editor window.
- If these shortcuts don't exist by default, can I create them?

I did just discover <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> ([ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/codebasics)), which navigate between "edit locations." This is handy, but sometimes it jumps around between different locations in the same file (depending on where you've been editing). Also I would love an option that moved through files sequentially, i.e not based on most recently viewed, but rather top-to-bottom according to how they are listed in the Working Files list.

Comment: The is an open issue about this in the vscode repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3260

Comment: I am using 1.17.0 (Mac) and for me I can navigate between all open files using what you suggested which cmd+option+left (or +right).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I like the idea of having commands for closing a working file or closing all working files and I can look into adding those for the next update.

As for navigation between working files: We have a very powerful tool for navigation called *Navigate History*. By default it is assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and you can leave the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key pressed and click <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the list of files, similar how you can switch between windows on the OS.

Navigate history is not identical to what you are asking for because it also contains files that you opened that are not in working files. Can you give it a try and report back if it solves the navigation problem for you?

We feel that this is a more natural way of navigating, because you don't have to worry about the order of working files. Instead you navigate across the list of most recently used files.

In our team we are so used to *Navigate history* that we cannot live without it anymore. Very often we would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> one or two times without even looking at the list that opens because we know that the file we want was either one or two history entries away.

**Update**

With the release of Visual Studio Code 0.5.0 there are now keyboard shortcuts to navigate back and forward in the list of working files. The shortcut is <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> (on Windows use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I appreciate the suggestion - I don't doubt that it's helpful and if that's the only option I'll probably rely on that. However I think I will always prefer having a selected group of files (like the Working Files) that I can navigate through sequentially. For myself the rub is that the list of "recent files" is, of course, always changing order, which makes it less convenient for me when I'm trying to jump between more than 2 or three files (since I never really know what the order is beyond that).

Comment: For the next update end of month there will be commands for navigating in working files sequentially (back and forward). I also added commands to close a file or close all files.

Comment: Heh, I just read this answer 15 minutes ago, then I see the popup "new version!", then I see you update.  You're on it, Benjamin.  Very impressed with the VS Code team so far.

Comment: oh man, I have been so annoyed by not having found this. Thank you!! I was so used to Sublime's default of just tapping cmd+p to toggle the last open file, but this is nice and adds a little bit more usefulness I think. Now just to train the muscle memory....

Comment: Have the shortcuts in the 'update' paragraph been changed since this was written? They're not working for me. (It moves the cursor to the top or bottom of the file instead.)

Comment: Cmd-K-Up is cumbersome as all get out. It feels like some kind of Vulcan hand expression. Why did they not use Cmd-Left and Cmd-Right like most other editors I've used? I will have to change this binding somehow.

Answer (score 41):

For Macs: from the menu, select menu *Code* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* to open `User/keybindings.json`. Then inside the square brackets, add:

```
{ "key": "shift+cmd+[",          "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor"},
{ "key": "shift+cmd+]",          "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"}
```

This binds the standard Mac tab switching shortcuts <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to switch to previous and next tab, respectively. It was tested in Visual Studio Code 1.3.1.

If you'd rather use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, the key strings for those are `"cmd+alt+left"` and `"cmd+alt+right"`. Although from my testing it looks like these are already bound to the appropriate commands by default in Visual Studio Code 1.3.1, so maybe this question is obsolete?

Comment: It looks like now both `⌘`+`⌥`+`←` and `⌘`+`shift`+`[` are bound by default to `workbench.action.previousEditor`, along with the respective opposite keys for `workbench.action.nextEditor`.

Answer (score 41):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

would be the best answer for navigating sequential tabs.

Comment: This is gonna help me a lot, I just discovered this alternative, and it's working on other programs as well! :D

Answer (score 9):

I'm used to having the numbered tabs being tabbable with your keyboard. Similar to Google Chrome.

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> # First tab

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> # Second tab

etc.

I did not find the settings for this in Visual Studio Code. I was able to map the keys to the arrows to be able to tab through one at a time.

```
[{
    "key": "cmd+shift+left",
    "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor"
}, {
    "key": "cmd+shift+right",
    "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"
}]
```

It is not ideal, but it will do.

Comment: I need same thing as this, cmd+1 -> #first tab and so on, how to do this?

Comment: @MohammadShahid and those that want the cmd+1, cmd+2, etc functionality as you might have been used to from chrome, sublime, and others, you can open your Keyboard Shortcuts and look for `workbench.action.openEditorAt...` section, you can then change those to cmd+1, cmd+2, and so on. Here's an issue and screenshot: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24753#issuecomment-294518439

Answer (score 8):

Linux default bindings for going to desired tab within current editor group is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
...

To change, menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard shortcuts* → search: `openEditorAtIndex`

---

Linux default bindings for switching between editor groups is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
...

To change, menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard shortcuts* → search: `focusFirstEditorGroup`, `focusSecondEditorGroup` ect.

Comment: I think keyboard shortcuts have been moved out of *Settings* in more recently versions of Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 7):

I also get annoyed with the default behaviour of cycling through recent files instead of working files, but it turns out you can re-map the keyboard to work a little differently.

To map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through working files similar to how other versions of Visual Studio work you can add this to your keybindings file:

```
[
  { "key": "ctrl+tab", "command": "workbench.files.action.openNextWorkingFile" },
  { "key": "ctrl+shift+tab", "command": "workbench.files.action.openPreviousWorkingFile" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around! But I miss the UI from the `Navigate history`.

Comment: Changed in Visual Studio Code 1.6.x:



`{ "key": "ctrl+tab", "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+tab", "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor" }`

Answer (score 6):

Use the [out of the box window management hotkeys](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_editorwindow-management).

Between Editor Groups

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to Left
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to Side
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to Right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> to Left
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> to Right

Within an Editor Group

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to Next

Answer (score 5):

Hold `ctrl` and navigate between files using `tab`, after selecting the file, release `ctrl` to go to that file.

Comment: And `ctrl` + `shift` + `Tab` for navigating backwards. And I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

New VSCode ver 1.36.1 on my Mac I have to do as following:

```
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+[BracketLeft]",
        "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+cmd+[BracketRight]",
        "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

what @Mesco answered still works, but the default bindings have changed to:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

To change them from default, you have to:

1. Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. search for: `openEditorAtIndex`
3. change keybinding to whatever

Answer (score 1):

You can install keybindings like Sublime Text, Atom or any other available on Visual Studio marketplace, look this:

*[Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings)*

Personally, I like the atom keybindings :)

*[Atom Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.atom-keybindings)*

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+PageUp`: SelectPreviousSuggestion
`Ctrl+PageDown`: SelectNextSuggestion

Answer (score 0):

I still prefer the approach you've described, but it seems the current solution in Visual Studio Code is to use keyboard "chords" as follows:

Previous working file - <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>;<kbd>↑</kbd>

Next working file - <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>;<kbd>↓</kbd>

Close working file - <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>;<kbd>W</kbd>

Note: On Windows/Linux, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

[Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings#_file-management)

Answer (score 0):

In windows you can use
Ctrl + Tab

Comment: Hi Akshay, can you elaborate on your answer? Multiple previous answers already contain the same information.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was to simply find the certain commands in the keyboard shortcuts and then modify them in a way which I prefer(Mac: CMD+1/2/.../9 respectively).
So navigate to VS Code -> preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts.
Then search for: `workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1` and remap your desired key to this command. 
Do this last step for all nine indices, so you can change between nine open working files.
For me this works best because it reminds me of changing between windows tabs on google chrome and etc.

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard Shortcuts]